# Нужна долгая обработка в контроллере ASP.NET Core без задержки на странице пользователя

Tags: asp.net-mvc

подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно организовать архитектуру приложения ASP.Net Core.
Задача: принимать большой файл от пользователя, обрабатывать его и возвращать пользователю обработанный файл. Проблема задачи в том, что обработка файла может занимать длительное время, пользователь же должен получать какой-то прогресс выполнения без зависания страницы. А также, WebServer может быть перезагружен, но результат все равно должен вернуться.
Вопрос в основном об организации правильной структуры выполнения данной задачи.

- Думал об использовании sginalR, но в документации написано, что нельзя передавать большие файлы, signalR только для обмена небольшими сообщениями.

Comment: [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: SignalR можно использовать для посылки сообщений о прогрессе с сервера на клиент, а также о том, что обработка завершена. После чего клиент может запросить готовый результат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо за рекомендации, подскажите пожалуйста, если не трудно. Эмпирическим путем я понял, что клиент (браузер) и инстанс asp.net core, обрабатывающий подключение клиента, при коннекте с хабом имеют разные connectionId. Как я могу узнать на уровне контроллера connectionId клиента? Я даже пытался сохранять список подключенных пользователей в хабе, но там тоже всегда создается новый инстанс. Либо я что-то не так делаю, либо тут есть нюансы, которые я не нашел (искал метанит). Возможно вы поделитесь полезной ссылкой, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если вас не пугает фреймворк Blazor, то  решение примерно такой же задачи, я встречал в [курсе по Blazor](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9xxo73r-uUOliwmcXy1iHr), только там требовалось  провести загрузку изображений из браузера, на сервер. При этом в процессе загрузки, нужно было также, настроить анимацию на странице. И это уже половина решения вашей задачи.

Первый этап.  Настроим вывод по условию, анимации загрузки на странице, и для этого, в блоке с кодом, можно добавить, вспомогательное логическое свойство, что то типа `private bool IsLoading`,  и  в основном блоке div, можно добавить условие `@if(IsLoadin) {}`, далее внутри этой ветки можно добавить вывод блока с анимацией, что то типа `<div <img src=`/images/loading.gif> . в ветке else, будет отрисовка основного контента страницы.

Второй этап, это создание класса с сервисом загрузки файлов из потока, и добавление такого сервиса в контейнер зависимостей.

Третий этап это создание блока на странице со специальным визуальным компонентом:

```
<div ><InputFile OnChange="..."></InputFile></div>
```

Четвертый этап, создание метода, в блоке с кодом на странице Blazor, который будет вызван в этом OnChange, можно назвать его например UpImage.
Далее пропишем сам метод:

```
private async Task UpImage() { }
```

В теле метода установим сразу `IsLoading=true` .
Далее добавим `try {} catch(Exception e)`

При этом для события OnChange, будет доступен специальный объект типа `InputFileChangeEventArgs`, добавим ссылку на него как входящий аргумент для метода, назовем его например просто e.
Далее в блоке try, в условии if проверим что хотя бы один файл был загружен из браузера, для этого запишем `e.GetMultipleFiles().Count>0` .
Далее в `foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles())`, можно извлечь название исходного файла, с помощью `System.IO.FileInfo fileinfo = new System.IO.FileInfo.Name` .

Пятый этап, это вызов сервиса для загрузки файла на сервер, и получение актуальной ссылки на место хранения такого файла на сервере.
Это может выглядеть примерно так: `UserFile.LocalPath= await _fileUpload.UploadFile(file)`. В данном случае UserFile, это объект описывающий файл пользователя в системе, LocalPath это место его хранения на сервере, _fileUpload это экземпляр внедренного сервиса. UploadFile, это метод из стороннего сервиса для загрузки объектов из браузера, специального типа IBrowseFile, в данном примере это объект file.

Шестой этап. После успешной загрузки файла, ниже, можно добавить изменение логического состояния загрузки изменив значение IsLoading на false. Что позволит прекратить вывод анимации загрузки и будет отрсована страница, с ее новым состоянием.